# Document.getElementById issue (accessing width attribute)

Tags: javascript, css, width

I've tried adding `.style`, `.style.width`, and `.style.width.value` to all parts of the JavaScript, but to no avail thus far.

Essentially, I would like two things.

1. To get an alert of the value of `50px` with the "Animate" button click, that runs the `anim8` function. In other words, I want the `width` of the `div`.
2. In a second set of code (`anim82`), I want to be able to set/change that `width` via a button click. I would like to add `10px` when the button is clicked. First, I need access to that variable though, the `width`, before I can change anything.

HTML

```
 <div id="mainTxt">Dag!</div>
 <form NAME="myForm" ACTION="" METHOD="GET">
 <input type="button" name="button" value="Animate" onClick="anim8(this.form)">
 <input type="button" name="button" value="Animate2" onClick="anim82(this.form)">
```

CSS

```
#mainTxt{width:60px;}
```

Javascript

```
var divAlert;
var divSize;

function anim8(form)
{
    divAlert=document.getElementById("mainTxt");
    alert(divAlert);
}

function anim82(form)
{
    divSize=document.getElementById("mainTxt");
    divSize.style.width=parseInt(divSize.style.width)+10+'px';
}
```

Comment: [Maybe it helps you.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.getComputedStyle)

Comment: Did you try `divSize.outerWidth`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
function anim82(form)
{
    divSize=document.getElementById("mainTxt");
    var width=divSize.offsetWidth + 100;
    divSize.setAttribute("style","width:"+ width +"px")    
}
```

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/PnvJt/)

Comment: This creates the the exact function I want.

I guess though, for the sake of being able to access some/any of the CSS attributes, I'm still wondering what I might do. Suppose I want to change the color, or left, instead of width. Is there some more universal accessor or navigator I may want to look into?

Comment: If you want to set other style property then you can use above mentioned way like `setAttribute` or you can simply do it like this  `divSize.style.color="white";`  see example http://jsfiddle.net/PnvJt/1/

Answer (score 0):

Your first step should be to see if you got an error. If you are receiving an error, try this code

```
var div1 = document.getElementById("mainTxt");
var align = div1.getAttribute("width");
```

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getAttribute)

Comment: if I use div1.getAttribute the way that you did, I get "null," despite having set the value explicitly. I've tried checking left or top and get the same thing.